# Flutter BLoc : Architecting a series of Flutter pages/routes and saving state

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

My flutter app has a series of pages which collect data (a series of forms). Every time the user enters data and goes to the next screen, the data is stored in my remote database. The user should have the ability to go back and change the data he entered. This means that every time the user navigates to a previous screen, the state of the screen needs to be retrieved. How can I architect this solution using Bloc (I am using the flutter_bloc package) ?

Here are some options I thought of

1. Use a single Bloc for all these pages and pass around the bloc to
   all these pages : If I use this approach, there should be a way I
   can retrieve the current state of the previous page when the user
   clicks the back button to re visit that page. I am not sure how this
   is done though.
2. Use hydrated bloc package - If I use this package, the state of each
   screen is persisted locally, so I can have a bloc per screen and
   retrieve the state of the screen if the user navigates back.
3. Use a bloc per screen : In this case, without persistence, I am not
   sure how I can retrieve the current state of a page when the user
   navigates back ?

Are there any other solutions through which I can achieve this (preferably using bloc) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If all of those pages share same UI/UX then it makes sense to use one bloc for all those pages, otherwise use separate blocs to drive UI.

Comment: are you adding those pages into backstack?, if yes, then pressing back button can restore the state of each page.

Comment: I am using a bloc per page now so every time you click the back button, it seems to be calling initialState, which renders a page with no data.

Comment: how you are navigating from one page to another? Navigator.of(context).push(something) right?

Comment: yes,  using named routing though

Comment: how you go back to the previous screen? using Navigator.of(context).pop()???

Comment: yes, thats correct